# App crashes when switching to intent from different package

Tags: java, android

I have 2 packages. Package one has the following FirstActivity.java class:

`package com.kacahotmail.mike.testfrom1;`

`public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
}

public void testFxn(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.kacahotmail.mike.testto2.SecondActivity");
    startActivity(intent);}}
```

and the manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kacahotmail.mike.testfrom1" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name="com.kacahotmail.mike.testto2"></activity>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Package 2 has an empty SecondActivity.java file (since it is just a test), and it has the following manifest xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kacahotmail.mike.testto2" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.kacahotmail.mike.testfrom1.intent.action.Launch" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The app crashes when I click the button from FirstActivity, instead of taking the user to the second activity. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In any case. Log is best helper in android. Please provide it.

Comment: I have no experience with this kind of programing but i think that you have two activities with `MAIN` and `LAUNCHER` intent filter. Maybe your `SecondActivity` need category `DEFAULT` instead of `LAUNCHER` and action `<action android:name="com.kacahotmail.mike.testto2.secondactivity"`

Comment: Provide a logcat of the error will shorten the debug process.

Answer (score 0):

Your Log output should help me give you a better suggestion. However you can also try the below code : 
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);

Comment: you can add the complete name to the secondActivity a to load the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Give the entry for activity SecondActivity.class in manifest file.